# CodeIgniter 3 - HMVC - Problema com rotas, Not Found ou falha ao Carregar Session.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, htaccess

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

Estou usando CodeIgniter 3 com o HMVC, enquanto fazia apenas desenvolvimento local, não tive problemas no XAMPP com Windows, subi para meu servidor de testes que é um Ubuntu Server e aí começaram os problemas:

As rotas pararam de funcionar **quando existem letras em maiúsculo na url**, os controllers do HMVC simplesmente não são encontrados dando erro 404 ou falhando ao carregar a Session.php o que é um típico erro de carregamento de bibliotecas/controllers e afim.

Eu tentei as seguintes soluções:

1. **Chamar URL em minúsculo:** Funciona, mas não é viável alterar o sistema por completo e ainda cair numa situação onde o usuário possa digitar a url com maiúsculo.
2. **Alterar arquivo .HTACCESS:** Pelos tutoriais que encontrei você precisa ter acesso ao http.conf para habilitar "RewriteMap lc int:tolower" e depois fazer a regra de reescrita, visto que no meu servidor só tenho acesso ao .htaccess isso não me resolveu.
3. **Alterar o Loader do HMVC:** Tentei, mas não consegui encontrar um ponto de entrada genérico onde eu conseguisse converter a URL base para minúsculo antes de fazer as chamadas padrão da classe.
4. **Alterar a variável $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']:** Tenho até vergonha de expor isso, mas sim cheguei nesse ponto como último recurso e gambiarras a parte funcionou, na primeira linha do index.php padrão do CI adicionei: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); e para minha surpresa funcionou.

Minhas dúvidas são:

**A: Apesar de conseguir resolver meu problema, não acredito ser boas práticas alterar a variável $_SERVER, como consigo modificar o MX_Loader para que ele torne-se definitivamente Case Insensitive?**

**B: A documentação do HMVC não é muito clara no padrão de nomenclatura dos arquivos, como eles estruturam a pasta 'modules', a minha estrutura de pastas está assim:**

www/application/modules/

www/application/modules/sistema

www/application/modules/sistema/Controllers/

www/application/modules/sistema/Controllers/Sistema.php

www/application/modules/sistema/Controllers/Catalogo.php

www/application/modules/sistema/Controllers/Rotas.php

www/application/modules/sistema/Models/

www/application/modules/sistema/Models/Sistema_model.php

www/application/modules/sistema/Views/

www/application/modules/sistema/Views/leiaute/estrutura.html

www/application/modules/sistema/Views/leiaute/menu.html

Pode ser que esteja nomeando os arquivos de forma incorreta e por isso gerou o problema da pergunta A por este motivo achei relevante colocar a pergunta B também.

Desde já grato.

Comment: Qual versão do CI que está usando?

Comment: Ops, esqueci desse detalhe, versão 3.0.6.

Comment: Por acaso, os nomes das pastas Controllers, Models e Views não deveriam ser minusculas?

Comment: No mvc padrão do CI sim, não me recordo no HMVC, parei de usa-lo, pois encontrei outra forma de trabalhar com os modulos do meu sistema, mas obrigado pelo apoio

Answer (score 1):

Já tive problemas relacionado, só que com nomeação de arquivos, No windows muitas vezes quando se nomeia o arquivo com Primeira letra em caixa alta ele simplesmente não considera, fazendo com que ao subir este mesmo arquivo para um servidor linux fique com caixa baixa. Porém o linux leva em consideração, pois o mesmo considera os arquivo em *case sensitive*.

No Windows existem "códigos" que estão lá somente para facilitar a vida de algum tipo de usuário iniciante, visto que como muitos esquecem a Caps Lock ligada, milhares de reclamações seriam feitas, pois a grande maioria dos programas não funcionaria , pois que o sistema diferenciaria UpperCase de LowerCase.

---

Resumo final: Dê uma olhada nos arquivo que estão em seu servidor linux, e verifique se eles estão mesmo com a primeira letra em caixa alta.

Comment: Esse não é meu problema, chequei isso no servidor linux e ta tudo de acordo, o caso são os controles de rota do plugin hmvc, por exemplo no CI original usando (:?) se não me engano, ele aceita rota case insensitive, mas no hmvc não.